# VMWare: Unable to access web server running on guest OS (Oracle Enterprise Linux 6.5) from host (Windows 7)

Tags: vmware-workstation, vmware-player

I am hosting a Oracle Linux 6.5 OS using VMWare on my windows 7 laptop. The VM is configured to use NAT networking configuration, and I am able to ping the guest OS successfully from my windows machine. Also, I am able to access internet from within my guest OS.
However, I am unable to access a web application running on port 8080 on a web server hosted within the guest OS using a browser in my host OS. The application is however accessible when accessed from a browser within the guest OS.

Some observations that may be of some use:
1. Neither my laptop, nor the VM have a static IP address.
2. I am able to ping my guest OS from host, and vice versa
3. Firewalls are disabled on both my laptop as well as the guest OS

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the above issue could be mostly because of firewall settings/rules enabled in guest OS OEL. To check the rules you can type `iptables -L -n` at bash prompt which will display FILTER rules (CHAIN INPUT/OUTPUT/FORWARD).

Adding filters to allow the host to access guest http protocol would make things work. On the other hand, if this is for developmental purposes you can completely disable the firewall filter by saying
`service iptables stop`. Keep in mind that this is not a safe approach as it exposes your guest to the world without a firewall especially if you are using a bridged network connection.